# JavaFX - Object with Constructor

Tags: constructor, javafx

I'm working with JavaFX and my Idea was to have my own JavaFX Object which I can create like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        TSS t = new TSS();       
    }  
}
```

My JavaFX Main class looks like this:

```
public class TSS extends Application {

    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;

    public void redrawGui() throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("tss.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;
        this.stage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("tss.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 
}
```

Normally the main method in TSS is called and its working but I want to create my own TSS-Object in its constructor, it creates the Gui.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `JavaFX Object` and why do you even want to have a reference to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaFX, you should (typically) think of the `Application` subclass as the "main" class (i.e. the application entry point) and its `start(...)` method as the replacement for the `main(...)` method in a "traditional" Java Application.

If you want to factor your code out into a class that is separate from the `Application` subclass (which is generally a good idea), then you can do so, but you need to just reorganize things a little:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TSS t = new TSS();
        Scene scene = new Scene(t.getView());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // not really needed in Java 8, but some IDEs need this to execute this class:
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args);}
}
```

And then you can define your own class as follows:

```
public class TSS {

    private Parent view ;
    private TssController controller ; // controller class specified in FXML

    public TSS() throws Exception {
        load();
    }

    private void load() throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tss.fxml"));
        view = loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController();
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }

    public void restartGui() throws Exception {
        Scene scene = view.getScene();
        Stage stage = null ;
        if (scene != null) {
            Window window = scene.getWindow();
            if (window instanceof Stage) {
                stage = (Stage) window ;
            }
        }

        load();
        if (stage != null) {
            stage.setScene(new Scene(view));
        }
    }

    public void doOtherStuff() {
        controller.doSomething();
    }
}
```

You could also consider implementing the `TSS` class above using the [custom control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) pattern described in the FXML documentation. I marginally prefer the style I showed here, as it favors composition over inheritance, but it is a minimal difference.